# List of dicts to/from dict of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to change back and forth between a dictionary of (equal-length) lists:

```
DL = {'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3]}
```

and a list of dictionaries:

```
LD = [{'a': 0, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3}]
```

Comment: It is unclear how you would interpret the order of DL? ie, if you have many elements, they loose their insertion order. If 'a' and 'b' come out of DL in a different order, what should the order of the resulting LD be?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perhaps consider using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([(0, 2), (1, 3)], dtype=[('a', int), ('b', int)])
print(arr)
# [(0, 2) (1, 3)]
```

Here we access columns indexed by names, e.g. `'a'`, or `'b'` (sort of like `DL`):

```
print(arr['a'])
# [0 1]
```

Here we access rows by integer index (sort of like `LD`):

```
print(arr[0])
# (0, 2)
```

Each value in the row can be accessed by column name (sort of like `LD`):

```
print(arr[0]['b'])
# 2
```

Comment: Nifty. Could you explain the difference between passing `[(0,2),(1,3)]` and `[[0,2],[1,3]]` to `np.array`? Specifically why does the second not work?

Comment: @Adam Greenhall: You are asking a very good question. I don't know the complete answer. I know that numpy sometimes makes a much greater distinction between lists and tuples than does Python. The documentation for dtype syntax http://docs.scipy.org/numpy/docs/numpy.doc.structured_arrays/ says, when defining a dtype using a "[l]ist argument ... the record structure is defined with a list of tuples." But I don't know why it must be this way.

Comment: @unutbu thanks, very interesting.  I had not heard of structured arrays.  The documentation link has now changed: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html.  Also, I note in the docs it says structured arrays "are meant for interfacing with C code and for low-level manipulation of structured buffers... Users looking to manipulate tabular data, such as stored in csv files, may find other pydata projects more suitable, such as xarray, pandas, or DataArray."

Answer (score 164):

For those of you that enjoy clever/hacky one-liners.

Here is `DL` to `LD`:

```
v = [dict(zip(DL,t)) for t in zip(*DL.values())]
print(v)
```

and `LD` to `DL` (all keys are **same** in each dict):

```
v = {k: [dic[k] for dic in LD] for k in LD[0]}
print(v)
```

or `LD` to `DL` (all keys are **not same** in each dict):

```
common_keys = set.intersection(*map(set, LD))
v = {k: [dic[k] for dic in LD] for k in common_keys}
print(v)
```

Also, please note that I do not condone the use of such code in any kind of real system.

Comment: LD to DL returns tuples instead lists, which may or may not be more desirable. BTW, very nice and handy oneliners

Comment: @GillBates You were correct; the code LD->DL code relied on all dicts to be ordered the same way, which is a horrible assumption to make. I've replaced the bad code.

Comment: To handle dicts with different keys:
LD[0] can be replaced by reduce(set.union, [set(D.keys()) for D in LD])
then [dic[k] for dic in LD if k in dic], so the resulting one liner is:
v = {k: [dic[k] for dic in LD if k in dic] for k in reduce(set.union, [set(D.keys()) for D in LD])}

Comment: I sure do enjoy clever/hacky one-liners. Also I think these are nice solutions that are very pythonic. They use core python idioms that I think python programmers should be familiar with.

Comment: Please - if using a clever hacky one-liner like this, add a comment, and preferably a reference to this SO answer. Your future self will thank you.

Answer (score 19):

If you're allowed to use outside packages, Pandas works great for this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(DL).to_dict(orient="records")
```

Which outputs:

```
[{'a': 0, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3}]
```

You can also use `orient="list"` to get back the original structure

```
{'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3]}
```

Comment: This is probably a version issue, but the above returns `{'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3]}` in pandas 0.18.1. `pd.DataFrame(DL).to_dict('records')`  works as described.

Answer (score 14):

To go from the list of dictionaries, it is straightforward:

You can use this form:

```
DL={'a':[0,1],'b':[2,3], 'c':[4,5]}
LD=[{'a':0,'b':2, 'c':4},{'a':1,'b':3, 'c':5}]

nd={}
for d in LD:
    for k,v in d.items():
        try:
            nd[k].append(v)
        except KeyError:
            nd[k]=[v]

print nd     
#{'a': [0, 1], 'c': [4, 5], 'b': [2, 3]}
```

Or use [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
nd=cl.defaultdict(list)
for d in LD:
   for key,val in d.items():
      nd[key].append(val)

print dict(nd.items())
#{'a': [0, 1], 'c': [4, 5], 'b': [2, 3]}
```

Going the other way is problematic. You need to have some information of the insertion order into the list from keys from the dictionary. Recall that the order of keys in a dict is not necessarily the same as the original insertion order.

For giggles, assume the insertion order is based on sorted keys. You can then do it this way:

```
nl=[]
nl_index=[]

for k in sorted(DL.keys()):
    nl.append({k:[]})
    nl_index.append(k)

for key,l in DL.items():
    for item in l:
        nl[nl_index.index(key)][key].append(item)

print nl        
#[{'a': [0, 1]}, {'b': [2, 3]}, {'c': [4, 5]}]
```

If your question was based on curiosity, there is your answer. If you have a real-world problem, let me suggest you rethink your data structures. Neither of these seems to be a very scalable solution.

Answer (score 12):

Here are the one-line solutions (spread out over multiple lines for readability) that I came up with:

if dl is your original dict of lists:

```
dl = {"a":[0, 1],"b":[2, 3]}
```

Then here's how to convert it to a list of dicts:

```py
ld = [{key:value[index] for key,value in dl.items()}
         for index in range(max(map(len,dl.values())))]
```

Which, if you assume that all your lists are the same length, you can simplify and gain a performance increase by going to:

```py
ld = [{key:value[index] for key, value in dl.items()}
        for index in range(len(dl.values()[0]))]
```

Here's how to convert that back into a dict of lists:

```py
dl2 = {key:[item[key] for item in ld]
         for key in list(functools.reduce(
             lambda x, y: x.union(y),
             (set(dicts.keys()) for dicts in ld)
         ))
      }
```

If you're using Python 2 instead of Python 3, you can just use `reduce` instead of `functools.reduce` there.

You can simplify this if you assume that all the dicts in your list will have the same keys:

```
dl2 = {key:[item[key] for item in ld] for key in ld[0].keys() }
```

Comment: What is the point of the rollback to version 4?  Note that you have made the range in the second code snippet wrong, and removing the python code formatting makes the code actively worse.

Answer (score 6):

The python module of `pandas` can give you an easy-understanding solution. As a complement to @chiang's answer, the solutions of both D-to-L and L-to-D are as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
DL = {'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3]}
out1 = pd.DataFrame(DL).to_dict('records')
```

Output:

```
[{'a': 0, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3}]
```

In the other direction:

```
LD = [{'a': 0, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3}]
out2 = pd.DataFrame(LD).to_dict('list')
```

Output:

```
{'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 6):

#### `cytoolz.dicttoolz.merge_with`

[Docs](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/toolz/dicttoolz.html)

```
from cytoolz.dicttoolz import merge_with

merge_with(list, *LD)

{'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3]}
```

---

#### Non-cython version

[Docs](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#dicttoolz)

```
from toolz.dicttoolz import merge_with

merge_with(list, *LD)

{'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3]}
```

Comment: Thank you @piRSquared for introducing me to the world of cytoolz. Where has it been my whole life?! :)

Answer (score 2):

Cleanest way I can think of a summer friday. As a bonus, it supports lists of different lengths (but in this case, `DLtoLD(LDtoDL(l))` is no more identity).

1. From list to dict

   Actually less clean than @dwerk's defaultdict version.

   ```
   def LDtoDL (l) :
      result = {}
      for d in l :
         for k, v in d.items() :
            result[k] = result.get(k,[]) + [v] #inefficient
      return result
   ```
2. From dict to list

   ```
   def DLtoLD (d) :
      if not d :
         return []
      #reserve as much *distinct* dicts as the longest sequence
      result = [{} for i in range(max (map (len, d.values())))]
      #fill each dict, one key at a time
      for k, seq in d.items() :
         for oneDict, oneValue in zip(result, seq) :
        oneDict[k] = oneValue
      return result
   ```

Comment: Does not work for me: `DLtoLD({1: [3], 2: [4, 5]})` yields [{1: 3, 2: 4}, {2: 5}] while I'd expect [{1: 3, 2: 4}, {1: 3, 2: 5}]...

Answer (score 2):

I needed such a method which works for lists of *different* lengths (so this is a generalization of the original question). Since I did not find any code here that the way that I expected, here's my code which works for me:

```py
def dict_of_lists_to_list_of_dicts(dict_of_lists: Dict[S, List[T]]) -> List[Dict[S, T]]:
    keys = list(dict_of_lists.keys())
    list_of_values = [dict_of_lists[key] for key in keys]
    product = list(itertools.product(*list_of_values))

    return [dict(zip(keys, product_elem)) for product_elem in product]
```

Examples:

```py
>>> dict_of_lists_to_list_of_dicts({1: [3], 2: [4, 5]})
[{1: 3, 2: 4}, {1: 3, 2: 5}]
>>> dict_of_lists_to_list_of_dicts({1: [3, 4], 2: [5]})
[{1: 3, 2: 5}, {1: 4, 2: 5}]
>>> dict_of_lists_to_list_of_dicts({1: [3, 4], 2: [5, 6]})
[{1: 3, 2: 5}, {1: 3, 2: 6}, {1: 4, 2: 5}, {1: 4, 2: 6}]
>>> dict_of_lists_to_list_of_dicts({1: [3, 4], 2: [5, 6], 7: [8, 9, 10]})
[{1: 3, 2: 5, 7: 8},
 {1: 3, 2: 5, 7: 9},
 {1: 3, 2: 5, 7: 10},
 {1: 3, 2: 6, 7: 8},
 {1: 3, 2: 6, 7: 9},
 {1: 3, 2: 6, 7: 10},
 {1: 4, 2: 5, 7: 8},
 {1: 4, 2: 5, 7: 9},
 {1: 4, 2: 5, 7: 10},
 {1: 4, 2: 6, 7: 8},
 {1: 4, 2: 6, 7: 9},
 {1: 4, 2: 6, 7: 10}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here my small script :

```
a = {'a': [0, 1], 'b': [2, 3]}
elem = {}
result = []

for i in a['a']: # (1)
    for key, value in a.items():
        elem[key] = value[i]
    result.append(elem)
    elem = {}

print result
```

I'm not sure that is the beautiful way.

**(1)** You suppose that you have the same length for the lists

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution without any libraries used:

```
def dl_to_ld(initial):
    finalList = []
    neededLen = 0

    for key in initial:
        if(len(initial[key]) > neededLen):
            neededLen = len(initial[key])

    for i in range(neededLen):
        finalList.append({})

    for i in range(len(finalList)):
        for key in initial:
            try:
                finalList[i][key] = initial[key][i]
            except:
                pass

    return finalList
```

You can call it as follows:

```
dl = {'a':[0,1],'b':[2,3]}
print(dl_to_ld(dl))

#[{'a': 0, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a generator, you can use something like

```
def f(dl):
  l = list((k,v.__iter__()) for k,v in dl.items())
  while True:
    d = dict((k,i.next()) for k,i in l)
    if not d:
      break
    yield d
```

It's not as "clean" as it could be for Technical Reasons: My original implementation did `yield dict(...)`, but this ends up being the empty dictionary because (in Python 2.5) `a for b in c` does not distinguish between a StopIteration exception when iterating over `c` and a StopIteration exception when evaluating `a`.

On the other hand, I can't work out what you're actually trying to do; it might be more sensible to design a data structure that meets your requirements instead of trying to shoehorn it in to the existing data structures. (For example, a list of dicts is a poor way to represent the result of a database query.)

Answer (score 0):

#### List of dicts ⟶ dict of lists

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import TypeVar

K = TypeVar("K")
V = TypeVar("V")


def ld_to_dl(ld: list[dict[K, V]]) -> dict[K, list[V]]:
    dl = defaultdict(list)
    for d in ld:
        for k, v in d.items():
            dl[k].append(v)
    return dl
```

[`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) creates an empty list if one does not exist upon key access.

---

#### Dict of lists ⟶ list of dicts

##### Collecting into "jagged" dictionaries

```
from typing import TypeVar

K = TypeVar("K")
V = TypeVar("V")


def dl_to_ld(dl: dict[K, list[V]]) -> list[dict[K, V]]:
    ld = []
    for k, vs in dl.items():
        ld += [{} for _ in range(len(vs) - len(ld))]
        for i, v in enumerate(vs):
            ld[i][k] = v
    return ld
```

This generates a list of dictionaries `ld` that may be missing items if the lengths of the lists in `dl` are unequal. It loops over all key-values in `dl`, and creates empty dictionaries if `ld` does not have enough.

##### Collecting into "complete" dictionaries only

(Usually intended only for equal-length lists.)

```
from typing import TypeVar

K = TypeVar("K")
V = TypeVar("V")


def dl_to_ld(dl: dict[K, list[V]]) -> list[dict[K, V]]:
    ld = [dict(zip(dl.keys(), v)) for v in zip(*dl.values())]
    return ld
```

This generates a list of dictionaries `ld` that have the length of the smallest list in `dl`.

Answer (score -4):

```
DL={'a':[0,1,2,3],'b':[2,3,4,5]}
LD=[{'a':0,'b':2},{'a':1,'b':3}]
Empty_list = []
Empty_dict = {}
# to find length of list in values of dictionry
len_list = 0
for i in DL.values():
    if len_list < len(i):
        len_list = len(i)

for k in range(len_list):        
    for i,j in DL.items():
        Empty_dict[i] = j[k]
    Empty_list.append(Empty_dict)
    Empty_dict = {}
LD = Empty_list
```

Comment: Hi Anup, can you please elaborate your answer with some explanation?